# json_modify in SQL Server 2019 script is not updating table when using cross apply with multiple elements

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, sql-server-2019

I have an SQL Server 2019 table with the following data:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable2 
(
    jsondata nvarchar(max)
)

INSERT INTO mytable2
VALUES ('
{
    "name": "Daily06012023",
    "documents": [
    {
            "imageUrl": "s3://2023/129/2312908000.tif",
            "json": {
                "indexingRecordId": "2312908000",
                "instrumentNumber": "2312908000"
                              
        }
        },
        {
            "imageUrl": "s3://2023/129/2312908000.tif",
            "json": {
                "indexingRecordId": "2312908001",
                "instrumentNumber": "2312908001"
                              
        }
        },
        {
            "imageUrl": "s3://2023/129/2312908000.tif",
            "json": {
                "indexingRecordId": "2312908002",
                "instrumentNumber": "2312908002"
                              
        }
        },
        {
            "imageUrl": "s3://2023/129/2312908000.tif",
            "json": {
                "indexingRecordId": "2312908003",
                "instrumentNumber": "2312908003"
                              
        }
        }
    ]   

}      
'      
)
```

I'm trying to use `json_modify` to update the `imageUrl` for a specific `indexingRecordId`. However, none of my scripts actually update the data in the json. Some examples I see want me to use a [0] document position, but I'm running these updates quite often in a json with hundreds or thousands of records so I won't always know the document position.

Does anyone have a suggestion to modify this script to apply my update correctly?

I've tried this script:

```
UPDATE mytable2
SET jsondata = JSON_MODIFY(jsondata, '$.documents.imageUrl', 's3://NEW_Path/2312908003.tif')
FROM mytable2
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(jsondata, '$.documents') AS documents
WHERE JSON_VALUE(documents.value, '$.json.indexingRecordId')  = '2312908003'
```

It says one record updated, but the data didn't actually get updated.

Does anyone have a suggestion to modify this script to update my data better?

Comment: Because there was no value in th JSON to modify. You can validate this with `JSON_VALUE`: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/LCjaQQjc) notice the last statement returns `NULL`.

Comment: `'$.documents.imageUrl'` isn't the same JSON path as `'$.documents[3].imageUrl'`. You'll need to come up with some 0-based row number magic to generate `3` from matching the nested `indexingRecordId`.

Comment: Thank you both! AlwaysLearning - your description gave more context to another example I found which didn't make much sense to me.  Seems weird to me that you have to know a document position before making an update.

I THINK I solved this with:
``

UPDATE mytable2
SET jsondata = JSON_MODIFY(mytable2.jsondata, '$.documents[' + j.[key] + '].imageUrl', 's3://NewS3Path/2312908003.tif')
--select *
FROM mytable2
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 j.[key]
    FROM OPENJSON(mytable2.jsondata, '$.documents') j
    WHERE JSON_VALUE(j.value, '$.json.indexingRecordId') = '2312908003'
) j;
``

Answer (score 0):

You can either rebuild the whole `$.documents` property

```sql
UPDATE t2
SET jsondata = JSON_MODIFY(jsondata, '$.documents', j.documents)
FROM mytable2 t2
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT
      IIF(
        indexingRecordId = '2312908003',
        's3://NEW_Path/2312908003.tif',
        imageUrl
      ) AS imageUrl,
      indexingRecordId AS [json.indexingRecordId],
      instrumentNumber AS [json.instrumentNumber]
    FROM OPENJSON(jsondata, '$.documents')
      WITH (
        imageUrl nvarchar(1000),
        indexingRecordId nvarchar(1000) '$.json.indexingRecordId',
        instrumentNumber nvarchar(1000) '$.json.instrumentNumber'
      ) AS documents
    FOR JSON PATH
) j(documents);
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/gT837SFW)

Or, if you only have one value to update (per whole `mytable2` row), you can grab its path and make that one update:

```sql
UPDATE t2
SET jsondata = JSON_MODIFY(jsondata, N'$.documents[' + j.idx + N'].imageUrl', 's3://NEW_Path/2312908003.tif')
FROM mytable2 t2
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT TOP (1) j1.[key] AS idx
    FROM OPENJSON(jsondata, '$.documents') j1
    CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(j1.value)
      WITH (
        indexingRecordId nvarchar(1000) '$.json.indexingRecordId'
      ) AS documents
    WHERE indexingRecordId = '2312908003'
) j
WHERE j.idx IS NOT NULL;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/qlhsbzR0)